# What is the best way to manage Laravel passport tokens when logout?

Tags: laravel, laravel-passport

I would like to know what is the best way to manage **tokens** in **oauth_access_tokens** tables of Laravel passport when **logout users** from API call?

Currently I have only set **8 hours** expiration for the token, and keep all the tokens there.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

If the users logs out then maybe you should remove them. You can add a subscriber to the log out event and do it from there. Take a look at:

https://laravel.com/docs/master/events#writing-event-subscribers

Answer (score 0):

`php artisan passport:keys --length=512 --force`   # create 512 character length tokens and etecetera